# Longest path in weighted cycle directed graph

Tags: python, algorithm, networkx, graph-theory

StackOveflow!

I am trying to create an Arbitrage strategy to get a better understanding of how to work with graphs. I am using python.

Graph:

[image]

Table format:

[image]

Task: find path of currency trading where we will get max profit. For example: `USD->EUR(0.75), EUR->GBP(2),GBP->USA(0.7): 0.75*2*0.7=1.05`, so we are getting 5% profit.

I thought that I can modify Floyd–Warshall algorithm or the Dijkstra algorithm to find not the shortest but the longest path. But it failed...

What algos are used for such tasks?

Comment: Longest path is NP-complete.

Comment: There are several articles/posts in the top results of Google search for "arbitrage medium log."

Comment: Shortest path algorithm like Floyd–Warshall or Bellman-Ford is the way to go. However you need for formulate the problem as a shortest path problem, where sum of some weights are minimized, instead of trying maximize of the products of exchange rates. We need to compute (-1 * log of exchange rates) as the weights in the graph, then apply Floyd–Warshall or Bellman-Ford to find the shortest path, because `minimization of sum of negative log` is the same as `maximization of products`. https://anilpai.medium.com/currency-arbitrage-using-bellman-ford-algorithm-8938dcea56ea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path that is the most expensive is found by

- find most expensive edge
- loop E over edges

  - subtract cost of most expensive edge from cost of E
  - set cost of edge to absolute value
  - end loop
- loop over all pairs of vertices

  - apply Dijkstra and keep best result.
  - end loop

Comment: Wow, thank you! Where I can read about it more closely? (about modifications before Dijkstra algo)

Comment: Am I right?
`for i in range(len(edges)):
    max_edge = max(edges)
    edges = [abs(i - max_edge) for i in edges]`

Comment: Or we max_edge only edges that we haven't used before?

Comment: Looks like you may be confused by the loop.  I will improve the psuedo code to clarify things.  The point is that the adjustment of edge costs is done once only.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I understand everything, that's genius!